# Looping vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Correction()

Dim i As Integer

For Sex = 1 To 2
For Age = 0 To 100

Range("Test1") = Sex
Range("Test2") = Age

For i = 4 To 145

Sheets("Input").Cells(i, 10).Copy
Range("Amount").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

If Range("Negative") = 0 Then

Sheets("Input").Cells(i, 13).Copy
Sheets("Input").Cells(Age + 4, 14).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

End If


Next
Next
Next


End Sub
```

when I try to run the macro, For `Sex = 1` , `Age = 0`, let's say After the Macro found that `i = 10` make the `"Negative" = 0`, the macro still proceed to the next i. But i want the macro to proceed with the next Age after find the `"Negative" = 0` for specific age.

Please kindly help me to fix this macro

Comment: Please provide proper background and state your question specifically. No one would be interested in understanding your code to provide you a solution. Follow this link on how to ask a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I can't make head nor tail of your code currently.

Comment: it's a bit complicated to explain the goal of this macro, I need to share the spreadsheet.

basicly in the coding, there are 3 For statement, but I want to exit this "For i = 4 To 145" if Range("Negative") = 0 happen, then proceed to next For which is "For Age = 0 To 100". 

to make it simple, I have 3 for statement, and I want to exit 1 for statement if my "IF" statement is fulfilled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited** after OP's clarifications

```
Option Explicit

Sub Correction()

Dim i As Integer, Sex As Integer, Age As Integer

If Cells(Age + 4, 12) > 0 Then

    For Sex = 1 To 2
        For Age = 0 To 100

            Range("Test1") = Sex
            Range("Test2") = Age

            For i = 4 To 145

                Sheets("Input").Cells(i, 10).Copy
                Range("Amount").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

                If Range("Negative") = 0 Then

                    Sheets("Input").Cells(i, 13).Copy
                    Sheets("Input").Cells(Age + 4, 14).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

                    Exit For  '<== this will have you exit the current for loop

                End If

            Next i

        Next Age
    Nextsex

End If

End Sub
```

I'd suggest to fully qualify the ranges you use. Since , as it is now:

- `Cells(Age + 4, 12)`, `Range("Test1")`, `Range("Test2")`, `Range("Amount")`, `Range("Negative")` are all referring to the current active sheet, which may not be the one of interest
- `Sheets("Input").Cells(i, 10)`, `Sheets("Input").Cells(Age + 4, 14)` are referring to the cells of a sheet named "Input" belonging to the current Active Workbook

maybe what above will actually work for you, but it'd be not a robust nor easily maintainable solution

Comment: really thanks, this can solved my problem, before i place the exit for after Then

Comment: If i want to make another condition to run `For i = 4 to 465` if the Cells (Age,12) = 0 , then where i need to add 
`If Cells(Age,12).value = 0 Then` and
`End If`

Comment: do you mean something like `If Range("Negative") = 0 and Cells (Age,15) = 0 Then ...`. otherwise add more info. Finally: you may want to up-vote any answer you find useful, and mark as accepted the one that fulfilled your original question. thank you

Comment: Sorry, ignore the second comment, what I mean is If the `Cells (Age +4,12) > 0`, then I want to run the whole macro. so where I need to put this if statement?

Comment: see edited answer. If the _original_ question is fulfilled you may want to mark it as accepted

Comment: Can we put the `if Cells(Age + 4, 12) > 0 Then` after `For Age = 0 To 100`, because I want the macro to enter the statement for Age then check the if condition?

Comment: I think we cant move the `If Cells(Age + 4, 12) > 0 Then` after the for statement,